# Am I allowed to run a javascript runtime (like v8) on the iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, c++

According to [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/v8-users/browse_thread/thread/3f57f8d1c31806a5), the iphone agreement says that it doesn't allow "loading of plugins or running interpreted code that has been downloaded".

Technically, I **would** like to download scripts from our server (embedded in a proprietary protocol).

Does this mean I wouldn't be allowed to run a runtime like v8 in an iphone app?

This is probably more of a legal question.

Comment: The SDK agreement has seen a few changes since 2008, should this question be reviewed, or at least the date/version of the agreement explicitely given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your interpretation is correct - You would not be allowed to download and execute JavaScript code in v8.

If there were some way to run the code in an interpreter already on the iPhone (i.e. the javascript engine in MobileSafari) then that would be permitted I think.

Answer (score 2):

This is partially a technical question too.  V8 as currently implemented won't run on the iPhone.  No JIT-based VM will.

Answer (score 1):

Well I embedded Lua into my application already and am programming most of the login in Lua and then downloading it to my iPhone for fast iteration, but this is only intended during development. Once I ship the scripts will be placed in the source and compiled into byte-code shipped along with the app just like any other resource.

I'd say this applies to V8 aswell.

Answer (score 1):

I concur. My reading is also that DOWNLOADED scripts are not allowed. Pre-installed and user-written scripts are fine. But it is a fine distinction and IANAL etc etc.